# Where should my Business Logic go?

Tags: c#, .net, business-logic

I have the following seperation of logic in my application, as you can see I have a class called SimpleController which is what I use to Import and Find SimpleEntities.

I read all the SimpleEntities into memory List cause I search these Entities very often and its a lot faster then reading from the database everytime I want to search for an Entity.

Would it be better to move the logic where I read and store the SimpleEntities into memory into the SimpleLogic class instead of the SimpleController class?

```
public class SimpleEntity
{
    public int SimpleId { get; set; }
    public string SimpleName { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleDAL
{
    public ICollection<SimpleEntity> GetAllSimpleEntities()
    {
        //Retrieve SimpleEntities from Database
    }   
    public void InsertSimpleEntity(SimpleEntity simpleEntity)
    {
        //Insert simple Entity into Database
    }
}

public class SimpleLogic
{
    private readonly SimpleDAL simpleDAL = new SimpleDAL();

    public ICollection<SimpleEntity> GetAllSimpleEntities()
    {
        return simpleDAL.GetAllSimpleEntities();
    }
    public void InsertSimpleEntity(SimpleEntity simpleEntity)
    {
        //Validate simpleEntity before adding to database
        if (simpleEntity.SimpleId <= 0)
            throw new  Exception("Invalid SimpleEntity Id: " + simpleEntity.SimpleId);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(simpleEntity.SimpleName))
            throw new Exception("SimpleEntity Name cannot be empty or null");

        simpleDAL.InsertSimpleEntity(simpleEntity);
    }
}

public class SimpleController
{
    private readonly SimpleLogic simpleLogic = new SimpleLogic();
    private List<SimpleEntity> simpleEntities;

    public SimpleController()
    {
        simpleEntities = simpleLogic.GetAllSimpleEntities().ToList();
    }

    public int FindSimpleIndex(int simpleId)
    {
        return simpleEntities.FindIndex(p=> p.SimpleId == simpleId);
    }

    public void ImportOtherSimpleEntity(OtherSimpleEntity otherSimpleEntity)
    {
        if (otherSimpleEntity.Operation == "Update")
        {
            int index = FindSimpleIndex(otherSimpleEntity.OtherSimpleId);
            //If entity was found update SimpleEntity
            if (index > -1)
            {
                //Call SimpleLogic.UpdateSimpleEntity(Pass in SimpleEntity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd perhaps implement a `SimpleEntityManager` which can be referenced from within the controller, and can operate outside it if necessary. So the controller handles the MVC aspects of the system, and the `SimpleEntityManager` manages the `SimpleEntities`.

As an aside, `InsertSimpleEntity()` appears to be performing validation on `SimpleEntity` fields. I would normally rather the `SimpleEntity` performs that validation *itself* (most likely during construction).

Comment: Ok, I agree with the SimpleEntityManager aspect. I also though about moving the Entity Validation Logic into the Entity it'self but then the Logic class doesn't seem to have a real use, it just calls the DAL and seems to be a bit of a waste.